# Bootstrap | Issue with responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am building a website using Bootstrap and I am not sure what the best way to tackle the following issue is.

I have a large logo on the left of my navbar and on the right I have six nav items. At an XS screen size the nav items correctly collapse into a burger menu, however before they do so they float below the logo, which shouldn't be the correct behavior.

Demonstration: try resizing this webpage -> http://stackoverflowquestion.bss.design

One solution to a similar issue on Stack Overflow was to simply change the collapse width - however I have found that this isn't optimal since different devices have difference heights/zooms so the width isn't universal.

What would be the best practice to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to generate custom bootstrap here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ with proper **Media queries breakpoints** you can edit there several other things. Bootstrap standard width and other parameters are just a basic skeleton - you can always edit them.

Edit: Other solution - just scale logo to smaller size - make it responsive (and use max-width).

Edit2: Scale down logo container div with media-query (and keep logo image responsive) - with that solution you can keep collapsed menu only for lower resolutions (screen-xs) and screen-lg/md will stay un-collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the break point where the navbar collapse. By default, it is set to XS screen i.e < 768px. Because of populated content, navbar-collapse is pushed under navbar-header.

You'll have to set the navbar-collapse break point to sm or md screen by changing the width. I haven't found any issue with this method.

Alternatively, you can use media queries to make navbar elements smaller and responsive. Such as you can make your logo smaller as the screen width decreases so that the navigation can fit in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to fix it. Remove the max-height in you navbar.